# Why git pull doesnt' restore deleted files?

Tags: git, pull

There're two remote repos on github:

`repo_course`: course instructor regularly release new assignment skeleton code;

`repo_me`: my own with completed assignment code to grade;

It works like that:

`git clone <repo_me url>`: create local working repo on my computer which is empty

`git add remote skeleton <repo_course url>`

`git pull skeleton master`: fetch skeleton code, complete it, and `push` to `repo_me`

My question is:

Suppose that I pulled `skeleton.java` and rename or delete it, then I `git pull skeleton master` again, it won't restore. Why is that? It seems `pull` will add the new skeleton files only once at the first `pull` since last time. What's the benefits of its being designed like this?

What should I do if I indeed need to restore my deleted files from `repo_course`?

Comment: `git pull` means `git fetch && git merge`: obtain *their* new work, then combine it with *your* work.  So: Why do you believe Git should *undo* your work? You removed the file. He didn't touch the file. Git keeps your change.

Comment: very enlightening, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your work replayed, instead of their work merged, try (with Git 2.9 or more):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a simple git pull will replay (rebase) your local commits (including your file rename) on top of what you are fetching.

> "Why git pull doesnt' restore deleted files?

Because a merge would override local modification (like the file rename) with what is merged.
As opposed to rebase, which will rebase your own local work (like a file rename) on top of what is fetched.

Comment: I'd 'copy' torek's comment before before it clearly says why it doesnt work as expected by OP

Comment: @Daij-Djan it will here: I changed the meaning of git pull, which in my case means fetch + rebase, not fetch + merge.

Comment: -1 sorry I dont get your comment and while this is awesome advice I miss the answer to the question: "Why git pull doesnt' restore deleted files?"

Comment: @Daij-Djan Sure: I have edited the answer for you to cancel your downvote.

Comment: looks better :) im still saying toreks commment was clearer but nvm :) thanks :)